# Is it possible to pass a reactive property in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

There is a code I take over from another developer. He used a Vuex property POLL to initialize some components. I wanted to use a different approach - get the object at upper level and pass it as a property downstream to the components. The object is fetched in async method from the backend. I thought that Vue reactivity will initialize real value later. But I get an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "poll" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <PollHeading> at src/components/molecules/PollHeading.vue
   <CompletePoll> at src/components/organisms/CompletePoll.vue
     <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
```

Home.vue

```
<Poll v-if="this.$store.getters.LATEST_POLL" :item="this.$store.getters.LATEST_POLL" />
... 
created() {
 this.$store.dispatch('GET_LATEST_POLL');
},
```

[CompletePoll.vue](https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/90c7a60a0c7579c314c08dc2bed73fb3481afab1/spa/src/components/organisms/CompletePoll.vue)

```
<PollHeading :item="item"/>
... 
props: {
  item: Object,
},
```

PollHeading.vue

```
props: {
  item: Object,
},
```

Am I going the wrong direction and the original developer was right? Or is there a way how to fix my approach? He used to do:

[PollHeading.vue](https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/71e20c6bb23bf42ddad0627b33364ec83816d524/spa/src/components/organisms/PollVoting.vue) (I renamed to CompletePoll.vue)

```
computed: {
    poll() {
      return {
        poll: this.$store.getters.POLL,
      };
    },
```

Comment: Did you tried to `mapGetters`?  Something like this: `computed: { ...mapGetters(['POLL']) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1)**

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "poll" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` means that you have this declared in `template` block of `.vue` file, but it's not declared in the `script's data property or computed`.  I don't see that specific `.vue` file where you use `poll` variable.

**Problem 2)** When you use variables in `tmeplate` blocks, you shouldn't use `this` .

So instead of this: `<Poll v-if="this.$store.getters.LATEST_POLL" :item="this.$store.getters.LATEST_POLL" />`

Write: `<Poll v-if="$store.getters.LATEST_POLL" :item="$store.getters.LATEST_POLL" />`

**Problem 3)** https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/spa/src/components/molecules/PollHeading.vue on this file you use `poll` in `template` but you don't have that variable created anywhere. your prop's name is `item` and not `poll`.  So change `poll` to `item` in `template` block everywhere in that file.

Comment: Hi, the complete source code is there: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/master/spa/src

Comment: There is an undefined error later: ypeError: Cannot read property 'poll' of undefined in /src/components/molecules/PollHeading.vue?vue&type=template

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: You are right, I noted it as well. Stupid old code. I fixed it, recompiled but it is still there. How can I instruct vue to print the line of error? It is hard to orientate when no context is given.

Comment: You should be using `sourcemaps` in order to see the actual file and line of error . The error should have been gone.